# CentOS with WebLogic versus RHEL?

Tags: weblogic, centos, rhel

I would like to switch over to CentOS for running WebLogic 11g which is currently deployed under RHEL. Have folks encountered any issues with running WebLogic 11g on CentOS that I should be aware of?

Comment: I have been running WebLogic 10gR3 in CentOS in production and testing environments since almost three years ago and have had no issues specific to OS environment. At least none that we discovered so. Hope it helps.

Comment: That does help-- thanks. Have you had to use openjdk or have you been able to run sun jdk or jrockit? Note, that is a two part question-- 1) have you run into any technical issues with those other VMs and 2) have you had to deal with any licensing issues of running sun jdk or jrockit on CentOS? Also, have you ever needed support from Oracle on WebLogic and have they supported you even though you are on CentOS?

Comment: I have always used JRockit with no issues (at least none that I know of so far), and I have never needed to contact Oracle support. Actually, the only two times I have struggled with this envirnoment are my two questions on SO: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332791/weblogic-10gr3-unsupportedencodingexception-parsing-content-type-header-for-mu) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168441/load-balancing-requests-to-a-weblogic-10gr3-rmi-server-on-amazon-ec2). Unfortunately, I cannot help you on licensing, as this issue is handled by someone else.

Comment: If you think it helped somehow, let me know and I'll add an answer.

Comment: Yes, please add your answer so I can mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been running WebLogic 10gR3 in CentOS in production and testing environments since almost three years ago and have had no issues specific to OS environment. At least none that we discovered so.
Also, I have always used JRockit with no issues (at least none that I know of so far), and I have never needed to contact Oracle support. Actually, the only two times I have struggled with this envirnoment are my two questions on SO: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332791/weblogic-10gr3-unsupportedencodingexception-parsing-content-type-header-for-mu) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168441/load-balancing-requests-to-a-weblogic-10gr3-rmi-server-on-amazon-ec2).
Unfortunately, I cannot help you on licensing, as this issue is handled by someone else.